# Partial View Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to show 1 input bar + 1 submit button on right sidebar reactively.

The problem is each time I submit the form. Whole page got changed rather than partially show the result of subscription (success | fail) while all other section stay same.

How to write Razor template in this user case ?

Thanks

Comment: Razor partial views won't do that as to the client, partial views are a part of the single HTML file that it receives.  If you want to refresh part of a screen you will need to use Ajax.

Comment: @intracept any thing that I can do in Controller such as setFlash("Success"), and reflect on the screen ? Just wondering what's the good practice.

Comment: If you need to go back to the server to get more information, it has to be either a postback (whole page) or an Ajax call.  You can handle Ajax request from your controller as separate Actions.